# Struggling to understand the Guardian API via Python

Tags: python, json, api

I am using Python.org version 2.7 64 bit on Windows Vista 64 bit. I have put together some code which is a combination of the authentication method using an API key that the Guardian support team have provided and some Javascript generated by their website's Content API code generator:

```
import requests 
def get_content():
    api_url = 'http://content.guardianapis.com/#/search?q=football'
    payload = {
        'api-key':              '',
        'page-size':            10,
        'show-editors-picks':   'true',
        'show-elements':        'image',
        'show-fields':          'all'

    }
    response = requests.get(api_url, params=payload)
    data = response.json() # convert json to python-readable format
    return data
    print data


{
  "response": {
    "status": "ok",
    "userTier": "free",
    "total": 1,
    "results": [
      {
        "id": "football",
        "webTitle": "Football",
        "webUrl": "http://www.theguardian.com/football",
        "apiUrl": "http://content.guardianapis.com/football",
        "editions": [
          {
            "id": "football",
            "webTitle": "Football",
            "webUrl": "http://www.theguardian.com/football",
            "apiUrl": "http://content.guardianapis.com/football",
            "code": "default"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I am fairly new to Python and don't know much Javascript. I thought this code would print results to the Python IDLE from the football section of their site. It runs without error, however it produces no output.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong and/or if I have completely misunderstood what this code is meant to be doing?

Thanks

Comment: I think 'return data' needs to go after 'print data'

Comment: @imcg hi thanks for replying. i've tried it both ways round. neither work unfortunately...

Comment: how are you running/calling it in idle?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham F5 - Run Module

Comment: @user3045351, the code in my answer should run using f5 run module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call the function to get output:

```
get_content() # you need to call the function


import requests
def get_content():
    api_url = 'http://content.guardianapis.com/#/search?q=football'
    payload = {
        'api-key':              'xxxxxxxxxxx',
        'page-size':            10,
        'show-editors-picks':   'true',
        'show-elements':        'image',
        'show-fields':          'all'

    }
    response = requests.get(api_url, params=payload)
    data = response.json() # convert json to python-readable format
    print  data  # put print first
    return data
get_content() # call function
```

Also having `return data before print data` means that`print data` is unreachable as your function ends when you `return data`.

Comment: i used that exact syntax and got an error about the api key being invalid! i dont know why as i messaged the guardian yesterday on google groups and they said to me that they had confirmed the key was valid(please could you amend your answer and remove it for me as well please? i included it in error - thanks)...i copied and pasted the API key from my web browser though...do you think i need to copy it over manually?

Comment: I actually thought you had made the key up as there was an error, I would imagine copying should be fine but it is worth a shot. On a side note I recommend using `ipython`, you can copy your code then type `paste` in ipython and just use `my_func()` to run. There are a lot of really cool features in ipython

Comment: ok will have a look at that. as for api key, ive messaged them again on google groups and will send them another tweet in a minute. in my original question, below the print and return statements, what is all that code meant to be doing? the content code generator is not easy to follow if you are a beginner. thanks

Comment: do you mean the json in the bottom of your question?

Comment: yes, that bit. they have provided this contents code generator: 'http://explorer.content.guardianapis.com/#/sections?q=football'...i can obviously see the code changes when you add filter elements in but im not sure of the context in which to use this code...like that is it actually doing?

Comment: that is the json returned from whatever search you entered in the generator. You access the elements by key the same as you would a dict. name that `data` and use `print data["response"]["results"]`